# Замена части строки динамически

Tags: c#, unity3d, строки

У меня есть исходная строка по типу `"msp.203.321.33"`
Мне нужно при определённых условиях перед первой точкой вставлять и заменять 1 строку, которая меняется. Чтобы это работало по принципу интерполяции (типа так: `"msp{нужная мне строка}.203.321.33"`).
У кого-то есть варианты как это можно запилить?

P.S. Хотел уточнить некоторые детали.

1. Строку я изначально не знаю и получаю ее из элемента
2. Строка которую я хочу вставлять состоит из одного или двух символов.

UPD: Спасибо комментаторам, у меня вышло что-то подобное. Только есть проблема с тем, что код нормально производит замену если приходит в конкатенацию 1 символ, если 2, то он просто вставляет первый. Вот код:

```cs
  private void UpdateVendorCode()
  {
     var _codeString = TempStorage.Subtitle; // MP.208.09.56
            
     var _sign =_lightsCharacter + _currentSizeCharacter; // "X" or "YX"
     var _firstDotIndex = _codeString.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal); // 1st dot index

     var _firstPart = _codeString.Substring(0, _firstDotIndex);
     var _lastPart = _codeString.Substring(_firstDotIndex, _codeString.Length - _firstPart.Length);
     subtitle.text = _firstPart + _sign + _lastPart;
  }
```

По сути результатом должно быть Либо `MPX.208.09.56` либо `MPXY.208.09.56`, но когда я выполняю действие которое должно вставить Y - оно просто заменяет X, а не добавляет.

Comment: `mystring = mystring.replace("mcp","mcp{нужная строка}“);`?

Comment: Вариантов много, на самом деле, идин из них выше. Но нужно несколько конкретных примеров разных строк, чтобы подобрать правильные решения.

Comment: Найди индекс первой точки и конкатенируй сабстринг до точки, новый текст и сабстринг после точки.

Comment: @Yaroslav Я примерно это и сделал, но есть проблема в замене. Я добавил код.

Comment: 'Debug.Log(_sign);'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

С помощью регулярных выражений можно в одну строчку.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var input = "A.x.x.x";
var result = new Regex(@"\.").Replace(input, "B.", 1);
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
// AB.x.x.x
```

Или вот ещё однострочный вариант, даже без регулярок:

```
using System.Linq;

var input = "A.x.x.x";
var result = input.Split(".", 2).Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}B.{b}");
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
// AB.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Элементарная задачка)

**Код добавления в строчку:**

```
private string strAdd(string original, string add)
    {
        string[] origM = original.Split('.');
        origM[0] += add;
        return string.Join(".",origM);
    }
```

Использование:

```
string result = strAdd("msp.203.321.33","xy");
```

Результат:

```
mspxy.203.321.33
```

---

Для замены можете использовать такое:

```
private string strRep(string original, string add)
    {
        string[] origM = original.Split('.');
        origM[0] = add;
        return string.Join(".",origM);
    }
```

Comment: элементарнее было в комментарии tym32167 под самим вопросом. А здесь кода в 20 раз больше без преимуществ в результате. Кода больше. Ресурсов требуется больше. Никаких преимуществ.

Comment: @Andrew, оу, и вправду, я чёт даже не знал что replace так работать может)

Answer (score -1):

Я решил именно таким образом.

```cs
  private void UpdateVendorCode()
  {
     var _codeString = TempStorage.Subtitle; // MP.208.09.56
            
     var _sign =_lightsCharacter + _currentSizeCharacter; // "X" or "YX"
     var _firstDotIndex = _codeString.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal); // 1st dot index

     var _firstPart = _codeString.Substring(0, _firstDotIndex);
     var _lastPart = _codeString.Substring(_firstDotIndex, _codeString.Length - _firstPart.Length);
     subtitle.text = _firstPart + _sign + _lastPart;
  }
```

Comment: а чем вариант tym32167 не подошел? Кода в 10 раз меньше, а результат тот же